# How to use an image rather than Activity Label in top-left corner of MainActivity in Xamarin Android (API 23)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

At the top-left corner of the main activity of my Xamarin Android app (using API 23) I currently have a simple text that is set with the command below.

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity Name", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/appIcon", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

This line is put just before the

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
  // code for main activity
}
```

and as a result I can see the text "Activity Name" in the top-left corner of  my app.
I was wondering how can I use an image instead in that top-left corner. I have seen that the Label property of the Activity class only accept a string, so the changing the Label won't work. But I have seen apps that have some icon or image rather than the activity name, so I was wondering what is the process to achieve this?

**EDIT**

I have tried with the following lines in the OnCreate() method of the MainActivity:

```
var actionBar = this.ActionBar;
actionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.appIcon);
actionBar.SetLogo(Resource.Drawable.appIcon);
//actionBar.SetIcon(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.appIcon));
```

but none of them works. There is no error, it just doesn't show any image but only the original text I passed as Label (in my example "Activity Name").
I also tried removing the label completely cause I thought it might take the whole space where the image is supposed to be shown, but that still doesn't solve my issue. I did this by adding also:

```
actionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

I am sure this is the right place for the code since if I use actionBar.Subtitle I can see the subtitle is added correctly in the action bar. 
Not sure if this is relevant, but I also have the following in the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: Application(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Material.Light")]
```

As mentioned, I am using Xamarin and API 23, to make my app comparinle,with Android 6.0+.

Comment: Do you mean after clicking [overview button](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/what-is-the-offical-name-of-the-third-on-screen-button)  in the minimize screen you need icon at top left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just had to add:

```
var actionBar = this.ActionBar;
actionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.appIcon);
```

*SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled* will force the icon to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code

```
var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;
actionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.newIcon);// add the newIcon in the folder Drawable
```

Comment: Hi, should this go into the MainActivity code, inside the onCreateView?

Comment: I tried both actionBar.SetIcon and actionBar.SetLogo but none of these work. I updated my question with what I tried.

Comment: actionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx));

Comment: This looks like Java? I am using Xamarin, how should this change please?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using API 23 (Android 6.0).